# PC lags like hell when i alt-tab from starcraft 2

Tags: technical-issues, performance

After I upgraded the system to service pack 1 and installed lastest graphics driver and **Starcraft 2** updates, my system start lagging when I <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>

I tested in both, window-mode and full-screen

In the window-mode it takes 5/10 minutes to occur.

I'm running **Windows 7**

Comment: Fullscreen or windowed mode? Try to change to windowed mode.

Comment: Are there other background applications running?

Comment: in windowed mode seems to run ok

Comment: Please provide some more details about your problem, and avoid asking if "anyone else experienced an issue". This is not a discussion forum, but we can point you to resources.

Comment: actually no. same happens in windowed mode, but its noticeable after 5-10 minutes of playing..

Comment: It just sounds like a shortage of RAM... when your physical need for memory exceeds what you actually have it drops it into the "pagefile" on the hard drive. When you need to re-access this memory (IE, alt tabbing to programs that were inactive before) it has to load those items back into physical memory and stalls hard.

Comment: well I have 3 gb. isn't that enough for sc 2?

Comment: @Katie - It is enough.  You have to understand when you run an application in the background, any memory it was using is then allowed to be used by another application, depending on how much it was using this can take CPU intensive task.  It sounds like your CPU is the entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reverting to the previous video card driver. If the issue was in the driver upgrade, maybe the old version will work better. If that doesn't solve the problem, it's possible it could relate to SP1. But I don't know what that could be. Another option would be to re-install SC2. This may allow the config files to adapt to whatever new changes are in your system.

Comment: I do not advise getting rid of Windows 7 SP1 mainly because I can guarantee you that is not the reason this started to happen.  Besides the SP 1 has installed security patches that should be installed.

Comment: Totally agree. Sorry if I lead anyone to think that. Don't undo a SP ever.. if there's bugs caused by them, MS usually fixes them pretty quick. And yes, like @Ramhound said, it's not likely that it's because of SP1